# Preparing a new workbook for save

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a macro enabled template for the creation of a Schedule of Values document for construction projects. As part of the setup process I would like to set the name(filename) of the workbook and prepare it to save as a macro enabled workbook with the appropriate name when the user decides to save. Is there a way that this can be prepped without forcing an immediate save or am I better off initiating a save as part of the setup process?

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? You want to prepare something when the user decides to save but you don't want to save? How would the user ever save? Or does a macro save for the user?

Comment: Sure.  The issue that I am having is that when I go to save the document that it defaults to a non-macro enabled spreadsheet.  Not a huge deal for me since I expect that, but I'm hoping to avoid the training issue of having to teach people to 'save as" a macro enabled spreadhseet.  What I am looking for is the spreadsheet defaulting to macro enabled and while I'm at it defaulting to a file name based on information contained within the workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    'do your prepping
    If SaveAsUI Then
        'do something (like open your own UI)
    End If
    'save workbook
    Cancel = True 'cancel the original save action
End Sub
```

However I think that has to be in the new workbook's module so I'm not sure if it will work for you...

Comment: Close enough that I was able to find a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @BarryBuehne Nice! Feel free to share your solution by writing a new answer or appending it to your original question.